# How can I print out a matrix in the following format in prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog

I am trying to print out a matrix in the following format but I am not sure how to. So this is the format I want to print it in.

```
************
***35****35*
***2938**28*
**28*2358*32
*3512**23*93
*28*3258*328
**92*329*21*
*318*5913*13
*53*28**2345
*84*8125*21*
**13**5329**
**12****58**
```

This is how I am creating my matrix, what would I need to change in order to print out it like the above?

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

%Create Matrix
setMatrix(N, Matrix) :-
        length(Matrix, N),
        maplist(length_list(N), Matrix).

length_list(L, Ls) :- length(Ls, L).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I answer the actual question, a few additional points:

1. Think in terms of **relations** between entities, and describe what holds. Wording like "create", "set" etc. make no sense in this view: The described entities come into existence by describing them in any number of ways, for example, by writing them down directly.
2. Taking into account the earlier point, you can for example use:

   ```
   n_matrix(N, Matrix) :-
           length(Matrix, N),
           maplist(same_length(Matrix), Matrix).
   ```
3. Notice that `n_matrix/2` can be used in **all directions**, including: using a partially filled matrix, determining `N` from a given or partially instantiated matrix, *testing* whether a matrix is an N×N matrix etc. Therefore, we have chosen a name that encompasses *all* such use cases simultaneously by stating what each argument stands for, using *declarative* wording.

And now in response to the actual question:

Try to answer the simpler question:

> How would you print a **single row** of this matrix in the way you want?

One way to do it is:

```
print_row(Ls) :- maplist(write, Ls), nl.
```

And now you can easily apply this to print the entire matrix:

```
?- n_matrix(N, Ms), maplist(print_row, Ms).
```

When describing relations over lists, it is often a good strategy to first define the relation for single element, and then to use the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)s `maplist/2` or `maplist/N` to describe the relation for the whole list.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it was very clear. I am very new to prolog and have been mainly doing Java so the prolog way of doing things is very strange to me at the moment.

Comment: That's to be expected. Java is very low-level in comparison to Prolog, so, no longer being dragged down with low-level details, you are now probably for the first time free to think about more interesting things, which are also harder to understand: Generality and omnidirectionality of the relations you define, finding good names for general relations etc.

Comment: sorry how would I apply it to the n_matrix which was declared? i mean how would i add to it. As that is in a separate file, which i am calling into SWI prolog.

Comment: Several ways. The simplest is to add the definition of `n_matrix/2` to your other definitions, in the same file.